# Scrollable list with resizable items

Tags: html, css

I need to put together a prototype of a scrollable list with items that can be vertically resized. For example, a list of charts. I wish I could post any code but dont even know where to start from. Tried googling but nothing came up.
Any idea what a good starting point might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would start with creating a list of elements in a vertical fashion. That should be pretty straight forward.

Second I'd reuse a library which may already have a resizable component that you can use. This should allow you to learn about resizable elements.
http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Finally, put them together and see where your bugs are!